# Traversable recursive node structures

Tags: scala, foreach, stack-overflow, tostring, case-class

I am trying to implement recursive traversions over a node structure:

```
sealed class Node(subnodes: Traversable[Node]) extends Traversable[Node] {
  def foreach[U](f: Node => U) {
    f(this)
    subnodes foreach f
  }
}

case class Atom(id: String) extends Node(Nil)

case class Molecule(atoms: List[Node]) extends Node(atoms)
```

Calling `toString` on an element like `Atom("test").toString` causes a stack overflow:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
at java.lang.String.getChars(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.scala:197)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.addString(TraversableOnce.scala:297)
at Node.addString(Fail.scala:1)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.mkString(TraversableOnce.scala:263)
at Node.mkString(Fail.scala:1)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.toString(TraversableLike.scala:615)
at Node.toString(Fail.scala:1)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.scala:187)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$addString$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:300)
[...]
at Node.foreach(Fail.scala:3)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.addString(TraversableOnce.scala:298)
at Node.addString(Fail.scala:1)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.mkString(TraversableOnce.scala:263)
at Node.mkString(Fail.scala:1)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.toString(TraversableLike.scala:615)
at Node.toString(Fail.scala:1)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.scala:187)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$addString$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:300)
```

Note that I haven't called foreach anywhere explicitly. So why do I get a stack overflow?

I solved this particular problem with an additional `TraversableNode` class and an implicit conversion from `Node` to `TraversableNode`, but I would still like to know what caused the stack overflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `toString` on an `Atom`, you're getting the one for `Traversable`, which [the documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Traversable.html) describes like this:

> By default this string consists of the `stringPrefix` of this
>   collection, followed by all elements separated by commas and enclosed
>   in parentheses.

The "followed by all elements" part is implemented [in `TraversableOnce`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L294) by calling the collection's `foreach`. Since your `foreach` first hits the `Node` itself, you immediately run into an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the `toString` method on case classes prints the class name and the list of its arguments (those in the first argument list). An exception is made to this rule, if your case class extends a class which has an explicitly defined `toString`.

Your `Node` extends `Traversable[Node]`. Note that it does not have a compiler-generated case-class `toString`, as shown in its AST (`scalac -Xprint:cleanup`):

```
case class Atom extends Node with Product with Serializable {
   ....
    override <synthetic> def hashCode(): Int = ScalaRunTime.this._hashCode(Atom.this);
    override <synthetic> def equals(x$1: Any): Boolean = Atom.this.eq(x$1.asInstanceOf[Object]()).||(x$1.isInstanceOf[Atom]().&&({
      <synthetic> val Atom$1: Atom = x$1.asInstanceOf[Atom]();
      Atom.this.id().==(Atom$1.id()).&&(Atom$1.canEqual(Atom.this))
    }))
  };
```

Above, the compiler "only" generates `hashCode` and `equals`, the `toString` is inherited from `Traversable`.

The `Traversable` trait from the `collection` package has a `toString` method which is defined in terms of `foreach`. Calling `toString` thus makes the `foreach` iterate on the node itself (in line with `f(this)`), resulting in an infinite loop.